# Codeigniter 2 and IIS 7 error 500

Tags: codeigniter, iis-7

I am trying to move a site from apache/linux to a server with windows and IIS7. 
Unfortunatelly when i try to enter the site it gives me

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I tracked down the line in code where it hangs and it is in /system/core/CodeIgniter.php here
line 359

> call_user_func_array(array(&$CI, $method), array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2));

Any idea where to look to solve this?

I should mention the fact that, the same codeigniter version, but with no custom code in it, works ok. So the problem is in my code, but the IIS dont show me any error and at this point I dont have access to any error log (if there is such thing on IIS).

Comment: yes - firstly start with a BLANK version of codeigniter 2 - i.e. download a clean copy - does that work? If so, slowly migrate sections of code across until the error shows itself

Comment: Did that :). 
Good idea, I am going to comment most of my code to see if is even working. Unfortunatelly I cant upload it proresivelly.

Comment: check the codeigniter log file - maybe something is getting dumped in there. otherwise what I meant was "migrate sections of code" by commenting out whole sections of your site until you kind of end up with an "empty" codeigniter site. eventually one of those steps will show the problem.

Comment: Yes, ty. I found the module responsible. Ty again :)

Answer (score 2):

What's your version of PHP?
Try changing relevant line (58 I think) in index.php from:

`error_reporting(-1);`

**To:**

`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);`

In PHP 5.3 "Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated". You can't pass variables to functions using the & like this (`&$CI`) anymore without PHP throwing the above error.

Setting the error reporting to ignore it should sort it.

Comment: I've tried and there is no output from php error reporting, because the output is a server error generated page.
The php version on IIS is 5.2.13 and in Linux dev is 5.3.3-7
Also removing & from &$CI didnt solve the issue.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?
Do you have PHP installed?
if you created a info.php file and put

`<?php phpinfo();?> `

in it then load that page in the browser what does it say?

Comment: Added version in previous message. I have to mention the fact that on linux I have no problem with the site.

Comment: Ok, I also missed the fact the parameters are wrapped in an `array()` so this won't be the cause...

Comment: Are you using URL-rewrites (routes)?

Comment: Also uploaded a fresh install of same version on IIS and it seems to work. The problem must be in my code, but IIS doesnt tell me anything.

Comment: Make sure in your php.ini file `display_errors` is set to On not Off